Docker контейнеры не могут общаться друг с другом по http в локальной сети docker
На сервере поднял контейнеры через docker compose, контейнеры находятся в одной сети local, локально сервисы общаются спокойно друг с другом по http, но на сервере происходит редирект, есть предположение, что это связанно с iptables
Пытался выполнять вот это, но ничего не поменялось
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING! -o docker0 -s ${DOCKER_NET} -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -s ${DOCKER_NET} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d ${DOCKER_NET} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ${DOCKER_NET} -j ACCEPT


Предоставьте пожалуйста docker-compose.yaml. Предварительно могу сказать что должна быть одна общая сеть у контейнеров и обращаться по внутренней сети нужно по названию сервиса, то есть, если у вас поднят сервис с названием api и внутренним портом 3000, то вы должны обращаться к нему по адресу: http://api:3000.

Не обязательно общий композ, но сеть должна быть общая внешняя в этом случае
